# Merging a grand children branch in GIT

Tags: git, merge

I'm in a specific situation and I'd like an opinion before messing up all my branches :-) Currently, I have this architecture :

```
master
   hotfix
   development
      p2
```

Recently, I had an issue and had to work on the `hotfix` branch. Now it's fixed and I merged it to the `master` one. Usually, when I deploy something, it's from the `development` branch, however, due to dramatic schedule modifications, I will have to deploy the `p2` branch instead of the `development` one. Indeed, the changes in `p2` must go live before the one in `development` (and the one in `development` can't go before the ones in `p2`).

Deploying `p2` is not an issue, but then I have questions about the next steps.

1. Is it possible to merge the `master` branch with the `p2` branch (in order to have the latest changes) without merging into `development` first?
2. If `1` is possible, I'd like to merge `p2` back into `master` once the code is deployed, but then, if I try to merge `master` into `development` (to put the changes of `p2` in `development`), will all the changes I made in `p2` be included in the merge ? I'm afraid that it won't be the case because of the first merge I did with `master` (as its latest commit has been done way after all the changes in `p2`).

Thanks

Comment: Short answer is : yes it will work, and, when you merge `development` and `master` in the future, git will not duplicate the commits in `development` which were already part of `p2`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat more detailed answer :

Your starting state is :

```
# sketch 1 :

*--A--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--* master
    \  \            /
     \   *--*--*--* hotfix
      \
       \
        *--*--B--*--*--* development
               \
                 *--*--*--* p2
```

You can merge p2 into master :

```
# sketch 2 :

*--A--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*-----* master
    \  \            /           /
     \   *--*--*--* h          /
      \                       /
       \                     /
        *--*--B--*--*--* d  /
               \           /
                 *--*--*--* p2
```

Once you have done this, git has stored the fact that the `B` commit (and all of the commits between `A..B`) is part of `master`'s history.

So later on, when you decide to merge development into master :

```
# sketch 3 :

*--A--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*-----*-----* master
    \  \            /           .     /
     \   *--*--*--* h          .     /
      \                       .     /
       \                     .     /
        *--*--B--*--*--*--*----*--* development
               \           .
                 *--*--*--* p2
```

it will only look at the differences between `B..development` (instead of `A..development`)

---

On these sketches, `p2` is drawn below `development`.

But git does not care about this notion of "below".

From git's point of view, `sketch 2` is the same as :

```
# sketch 2':

         *--*--*--*  h
       /            \
*--A--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--* master
    \                        /
     \            *--*--*--* p2
      \         /
       \       /
        *--*--B--*--*--* d
```

And `sketch 3'` may be clearer in showing how git resolves the new "forking point" between `master` and `development` :

```
# sketch 3':

         *--*--*--*  h
       /            \
*--A--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*------* master
    \                        /      /
     \            *--*--*--*       /
      \         /                 /
       \       /                 /
        *--*--B--*--*--*--*--*--* development
```